# How to get the label of a field Soql

Tags: soql, remote-action, label

I am doing a remote action in which I am getting a soql result return to js. Now in my js i am displaying a list of records but with the record I want to display the field label not the api name. How can I get the label of field while doing soql. As the it is a remote action I am only getting the return to my script. Is their any way to achieve it. Because I have a map which contain api name with label which i am not able to access in my js bec it is not returning from remote action method. Can any one help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. You are not really asking the right question here as what you seek is only possible through other means.

Answer (score 1):

In `VisualForce` you can use the `$ObjectType` global variable to get what you need. For example:

```
{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Name.Label}
```

This can also be accomplished dynamically:

```
{!$ObjectType['My_Object__c'].fields['My_Field__c'].Label}
```

If for some reason this is not sufficient, you can use describes via `Apex`:

```
String myFieldLabel { get { return My_Object__c.My_Field__c.getDescribe().getLabel(); } }
```